# In-app purchase UIViewController dismissed after SKPaymentQueue addPayment

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I'm creating an app for iPhone and iPad with In-App Purchasing, however I'm having issues on iPhone. When I tap one of my purchasable items, once the `SKPayment` is added to the `SKPaymentQueue`, my ViewController dismisses itself, leaving the payment unprocessed. This was causing a crash until I added `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self]` to my `dealloc`.

Once I re-launch the app, it will process the payment as expected and grant the user the content they purchased. It will not process the payment unless it has been totally exited out of and re-launched.

The way I'm adding the payment is as follows:

```
- (void)purchaseConnector: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SKProduct *selectedProduct = productDetailsList[indexPath.row];
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:selectedProduct];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}
```

after which it enters here:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The transaction's state is `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing` and thus continues, after which the ViewController dismisses and the 'Confirm Your In-App Purchase' `UIAlert` pops up.

Again, all works perfectly as expected for iPad, these issues only show up using iPhone.

**Edit**

I want to clarify, the issue is that the store ViewController is dismissing. I never dismiss it myself and cannot seem to step through where it receives that command. The dismissing doesn't happen on iPad, just iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

your code looks fine.

Just have a look at [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases) in case you've missed out something.